# Could black holes affect day length on Earth?

Tags: black-holes

What i mean to ask and call me silly but if being closer to black holes slows down time, in a way, wouldn't that affect us here on earth if say a black hole went by us. I know distance matters and i saw the jumble of math for the equation to see the time difference.

One other thing if there is a line of distance from the black hole distance wise to effect space time and it was half way threw the planet and was in a stationary orbit what would happen on the side that is close enough to experience the difference?

Comment: Could we feel say, a half second change is space and time, would we notice? if black holes collide and push out massive amounts of energy how do we know if we are being affected in small ways, or not at all, by them?

Answer (score 0):

> closer to black holes slows down time, in a way, wouldn't that affect
>   us here on earth if say a black hole went by us.

Yes. But it is very important to note that *you wouldn't notice*. You would not see the time changing on Earth, you'd see the rest of the universe slowing down.

> One other thing if there is a line of distance from the black hole
>   distance wise to effect space time and it was half way threw the
>   planet and was in a stationary orbit what would happen on the side
>   that is close enough to experience the difference?

Oh, interesting. Well I'm not going to do the math right now, but I suspect that this is physically impossible. In order to have enough of a difference from one side to the other to notice, the planet would be pulled apart. I'd have to run the numbers though.

Comment: "you'd see the rest of the universe slowing down" so you WOULD notice ? and wouldn't you see the universe speading up instead of slowing down ?

Comment: You would notice a change, just not on Earth. The day would not change, for instance, which was your original question.